# How to get public facebook page's news feed contents without user authentication/access token?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I am working on the iOS app, which needs to fetch news feed from public FB page.
I don't want to show authentication dialog as it's a public page.
For e.g. candycrushsaga, cocacola
Does anyone know facebook graph api allows this without accesstoken or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, figured it out. Graph APIs need auth token before making any calls to specific API. So first grab the access token via oAuth API and then make Graph API call with the access token.